# A javascript for selecting a ul having same href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
                    <li class="active"><a style="font-size:15px;font-weight:500;" href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Credit Card</a></li>
                    <li><a style="font-size:15px;font-weight:500;" href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Debit Card</a></li>


                  </ul>






 <script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {
    $('button').on('click', function () {
        if ($("#home").hasClass("active")) {
            $('.selectedRadioValue').val('radio1');
        } else if ($("#profile").hasClass("active")) {
            $('.selectedRadioValue').val('radio2');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

But both the href are the same. Can I make the javascript identify them with out the href? I want the href of the both to be same. Keeping the href same, I would like to make the javascript work. Instead of  `if ($("#home")` and `if ($("#profile")`, can I have something else to identify this?

Comment: `$("#home")` looks for an element with the *id* of "home", which doesn't even exist in your markup. I think you need to go back to basics as it doesn't sound like you really know what your code is doing.

Comment: More details needed.? what do you want to accomplish.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can give each of the links an id, like this:

```
<a href="#home" id="creditCard">Credit card</a>
<a href="#home" id="debitCard">Debit card</a>
```

Then you can select them by their id: `$("#creditCard")` or `$("#debitCard")`.

---

By the way, your current code will not perform as you are expecting. `$("#home")` selects an element with the id "home", not an element with "#home" as the `href` attribute. If you are wanting to select a link that has "#home" as the `href` attribute, you would use this selector: `$("a[href=#home]")`.

Answer (score 0):

There are several possibilities :

1. Select by ID or Class

   `$("#ID or .Class")` selector
2. Use jQuery.find() to find the required element :

   `$(".nav").find(".active");`

The above syntax will find active element and later you can perform logic on the same..

I would prefer 2nd way...

Answer (score 0):

I think you trying to achieve something like this:

```
<ul>
  <li><a class="active" data-radio="radio1">Credit Card</a></li>
  <li><a class="active" data-radio="radio2">Debit Card</a></li> 
</ul>
```

and on javascript side you can write in generic way as follows:

```
$('button').on('click', function () {
  var valueForSelectedRadio = $('.active').data('radio');
  $('.selectedRadioValue').val(valueForSelectedRadio);    
});
```

Notice the use of 'data-radio' attribute and fetching it's value in jquery with ".data('radio')" method.

Check the jquery API here:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/